# Cycles option to turn off texture tiling?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

### Update

As of 2.76 there is a [built-in option to handle this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34769/599).

---

In Blender Internal there was an option to turn this off (called [*Clip*](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/image.html#image-mapping))

Is there a way to do this with Cycles?
I know you can just scale your textures up with a transparent background, but you end up with textures much bigger than they need to be.

Is there a way to this, and if not, why not?

Comment: Where is the clip option? Link is broken

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ Are you referring to the BI link? If so, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cycles node system is very flexible and allows you to manipulate the UVs in pretty much any way you like.

The UV channel can be used as if it were just an image where U and V correspond to red and green channels.
These can be separated and manipulated using math nodes to create a mask you can use to clip the texture. 
Here's a screenshot of a node setup doing that:

[image: screenshot of suggested node setup]

This uses the clip mask group to mix the texture to black. You could also use it in a mix material node to mix with a transparent shader or the like.

While making such node groups is a relatively long process, you can append or link the node group whenever necessary after you've made it once.

Comment: what are those places where a node is connected to the connector between to other nodes??

Comment: @gandalf3 they are reroute nodes, they don't have any futional purpose, they're there just to make the setup clearer. You can add them by shift-dragging over a connection.

Answer (score 16):

As of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBf29625922f61c772e01a9bf2902a41bd4e4e264e) (will be in 2.76), there is now an option to set the coordinate extension mode similar to BI:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use the mapping node and check the min and max boxes.
Set the number of repeats in the values next to max check boxes.

Check my example here:
 [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62273197/MappingNode.png]

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work, sort of. I guess I still don't understand how the mapping node works. I can't change the size of the texture. Textured, Material, and Rendered views all display different results.. If someone can explain the the mapping node in detail, maybe that will help.

Comment: Yeah.. the location, rotation and scale values are in fact weird. My workaround is to create a separate UV layout to position the "decal" exactly where I want. Then I use the min and max check boxes to avoid tiling.

Comment: It should be noted that with this technique, [the outer pixels will be stretched](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/uv-mapping-stretch-issue-in-cycles). If the outer pixels are all transparent, then it works great.

Comment: @gandalf3, Why exactly are the outer pixels stretched?  I've run into this problem quite a lot.

Comment: @AnsonSavage When the texture coordinates are clamped to 0..1, all coordinates outside of that range will be equal to 0 or 1. Pixels that are mapped to exactly 0 or 1 (along an edge) will be mapped everywhere there is a 0 or 1, "duplicating" them on the clamped coordinates and giving a stretched appearance. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2629/599 for ways to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

Ooh! I just had to deal with this the other day.

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239416-tileable-uv-textures-in-cycles  
&
http://www.andreucabre.com/2012/02/multiple-uvs-and-decals-in-cycles.html

Those are the tutorials that I found helpful.  Unfortunately, as far as I could tell, it's really a longer explanation than can be laid out here, but I found those tutorials only after a dangerous trip to Mordor and back... 


Hopefully it'll save you some time hunting them down. Cheers!

Comment: the one on blender artists seems like the simplest way of doing it, but I couldn't get it to work.. seems only to work for where your uv map is _not_ bigger than the texture?