# UV Mapping: Skewed Tile Image

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a .jpg image that I want to used as a tiled texture for blender.
So I unwrapped my object (a cuboid with beveled edges) and added the image to the UV/Image editor. I clicked "Coordinates: Repeat" so that the image gets tiled.

Since I use Cycles Render, I added a node (image texture) and added the color output to the input of the Diffuse BSDF.
Unfortunately, the image is display skewed on the real object, though it is displayed corretly in the UV/image editor.

Here is a screenshot (skewed image left on the object, correct image right bottom in the UV editor):
[image]

How can the image be display correctly (unskewed) on the object? Thanks!

Comment: Does the object has transforms applied, particulalry scale (`Ctrl`+`A` > *Scale*) ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure, but I believe that you mean "rotated 90°" by "skewed."

You can use a *Mapping* node in a setup similar to the one below.

[image]

*Note that this is both an older version of Blender, and gandalf3's image from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/how-to-use-the-mapping-node) BSE question.*

From here, I would suggest feeding 90° and -90° values into the *Rotation:* sockets until your cubeoid  looks right. Do note that the *X*, *Y*, and *Z* values are not related, so what you do to one of them will not affect the others.

Comment: @cegaton Did you read the caption under the photo?