# Using a mapping node to disable tiling is streaching texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texturing, uv, node-editor

I'm having a bit of an issue getting started with UV mapping in Cycles.  It works fine initially, but when I add the mapping node and set min/max to the default values to turn off repeating, I get the following stretch.

This is a bit boggling to me as I followed multiple tutorials where this exact same process works.  See [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Lw-YHoxpAnk#t=537)

Images of the issue: [image: http://imgur.com/a/0Ezqd]

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cycles option to turn off texture tiling?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/cycles-option-to-turn-off-texture-tiling)

Comment: @Aldrik Interesting. I tried out the node maps on that other question and while neither worked the question mentioned something about making the image texture larger than needed.  So I increased the image canvas by 1px on all sides and the stretch went away.  I assume it's now stretching the transparent pixel but it's not visible.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by [Róbert László Páli](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2634/599), this is an artifact of the way the mapping node works.

You can get around this using [hjaarnio's technique](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1272/599):

Using this node setup that creates a map of where the image is:

[image: Example image]

Values in the 0-1 range are where the original image is, so if we use that as a mix factor:

[image]

It will use the Image texture only where the original image is mapped, and *Base Color* everywhere else.

Base Color can be a texture or even another shader as well:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Enabling the *min* and *max* values for the mapping does the following:

When the coordinate for the UV is above the one
(when a certain point is above the image on
the UV) then it changes that value to one.

So the sampler will sample a pixel from the coordinate
one, which is the topmost pixel of the image (and also
the zero value is sampled from there). So for every
point that is UV-mapped above or below the image,
the color will be from the top row of the image.
The same applies to the other direction.

A dummy solution would be to add one pixel
transparent black border to the image to achieve
a decal on the mug. But you have to use the alpha
channel to mix the image with the original color.