# Cycles Material: How to make a UV image not tile?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, image

I am trying to figure out how if there is an easy way in Blender Cycles to UV Project an image and nave it so it only appears once across the mesh.

I have attached a screen shot of the bottom corner of a rectangular plane where I want to project the image, but only have it appear on the front face.

As you can see the image is currently repeating and tiling onto the sides and back of the mesh. I want to eventually have the material appear as glass and be semi transparent. having the image tile across the back will become problematic.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Pinterest image of screen shot]

Comment: Go to the UV/Image Editor while in Edit Mode and scale as desired.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1258/2217 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2629/2217