# How to only use a texture once?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I have a burn mark texture and the problem is that when I put it on a plane and adjust the UV mapping instead of there being one burn mark loads show up. How do I get only one?

Comment: in the texture tab under image_Mapping select Clip for the extention

Comment: @Chebhou I cant find it. Is this on cycles?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1258/2217 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2629/2217

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add a mapping node between the texture coordinates and the image texture in your nodes. Then check the *Min* and the *Max* check boxes on the *Mapping* node.
Those two check boxes will limit the repeating of the image. Use *Min* to control the side to the left of the image, and *Max* for the right. With both checked neither side will repeat.
[image: cycles material nodes]