# Two Different Materials in One Particles System

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I wanna make a carpet with two different materials (some part is glossy and the rest is diffuse) using only one plane and one particles system.

How to do that

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5069/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8706/599

Answer (score 5):

You can use a black and white texture mask (in this case the alpha channel of the blender logo) to mix between two shaders:

[image]

[image]

Note that you need to UV unwrap your plane in order for this to work:

1. With the plane selected, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode.
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
3. Press <kbd>U</kbd>*> Unwrap*.