# Can hair particles acquire color from emitter's UV-mapped image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, particles

This is a bit convoluted (and I'm still wrapping my head around Blender in general) so bear with me:

I'm trying to create downy feathers on a robin.  I created a basic hair system, cranked up the clumping for a feathery look, made a few weight maps to control distribution and length, and so far so good: fluff achieved.

But what I'd really like to do at this point is to control the color of the fluff based on where it is on the model.  I have a texture mapped to the mesh already (to cover any bald spots that might show through) but that's not doing me much good since the fluff is covering it.

Do I have to make a separate system for the red breast?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9018/599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, In cycles.

In the hair's material, simply add an image texture, and plug it into the color factor as such:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using internal render. If an object has a UV map and that texture is assigned to the particle system, the hairs will inherit the colour from the texture.

You may also combine multiple textures using a blend texture set as stencil allowing you to have a different texture map for root and tip (or more).

Comment: Additionally, if you switch from the particles to textures you will get a slightly different window (object>part-system>texture). This allows you to finely control hair generation with UV maps or procedural textures.