# Color hair particles by emitter's texture

Tags: texturing, particles, hair

Following [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-hair-particles-acquire-color-from-emitters-uv-mapped-image) I wish to color my particles based on the emitter's texture.
The problem is, the feathers of my papagei don't even remotely look like the colors from the base mesh's texture. 
Here's what I see in the viewport. The mesh has the paint I assigned to it. 
[image] I turned off the feathers for now, they are white btw. 
Next is my material setup for the mesh (which is also assigned to the hair):
[image]
[image]

This featherColors material is what determines the color. 
And lastly I present a quick preview render from the viewport, which is all brown-ish. Note that the mesh itself is colored brown as well for no apparent reason.

[image]

Could someone lend me a hand so the feathers pick up their colors from the emitter's texture? 
Note that by "feather" I really just mean clumped hair particles. Those are not individual meshes.

Answer (score 1):

Sod it, broke the connection in the material between `Attribute` and `Image Texture` and the problem is solved.

Comment: Yup.  Notice that the answer in the post you linked specified a UV map name in the attribute node.  This may have been necessary in the past; now, an image texture will use your selected UV map as a default if no vector is specified.