# Particle color from emitter's shader color without any textures

Tags: materials, particles, hair

Using the `Texture Coordinate` node with `From Instancer` checked, I can assign particle's color based on the emitter's texture.

> **NOTE**: I am aware of previous questions that address a generally similar issue, such as this [one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted), for instance. However, none of the answers in these questions address my problem. They are all related to inheriting color from a texture. I want to inherit the surface color from Blender shaders, when using multiple materials on the emitter.

However, I can't seem to find a way to assign the particle color if I am only using simple shaders with no textures.

Let me show you an example of what I am trying to achieve. Let's say I have a plane that looks like this:

[image: Plane with two materials]

This plane uses two simple emission shaders, one for each half.

[image: Material slots]

If I create a `hair` particle system, this is what I get:

[image: Hair particle system rendered as Path]

By default, the particle system is using the `Path` option in the Render panel, and it seems to give me the option to use only **one** of the available material slots.

[image: Particle render settings]

What I want to do is to swith the `Render As` setting to `Object` and create a material for the particle that inherits the surface color of the face from which the particle was emitted.

So, if I have something that looks like:

[image: Particle system rendered with Object]

...I would like the cones on the red side to be red and the cones on the green side to be green.

I can of course achieve this result by creating **two** different particle systems that use different materials and then control where these particles appear using vertex groups. However, I would like to see if there is a way to achieve what I want using just **one** particle system and the material assigned to the particle object.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13466 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58200 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166840 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207

Comment: You have incorrectly flagged my question as a duplicate. I specifically said that I don't want to assign the particle color from a texture. I have already seen the previous questions you have linked to and none of them answer my question. Please read my question carefully and you will see that it is not a duplicate.