# How to conform a mesh ontop of another mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I wanted to give my character a circle of differently colored belly fur, so I tried to place a circle onto the body.

[image: Added circle]

I was having trouble figuring out how to attach this to the main body, snapping didn't seem to work to actually conform everything **onto** the body mesh, and moving manually is far too fiddly.

After searching for solutions I tried a Shrinkwrap modifier, but if this is an appropriate method I can't seem to make it work.

[image: Added Shrinkwrap modifier]

I would appreciate suggestions for how to make this work, or an alternative that might work better.

Comment: It's better edit the mesh and use a different material to the belly.

Comment: your model needs more resolution to shrink wrap on top of another model. for better understanding try shrink warp a plane that you subdivided 3 times or more on your model.

Comment: @LeoNas Yes, that would work if there was a way to add a simple circle of vertices to the original mesh, that doesn't involve something tedious like the knife tool going vertex by vertex. Do you have such a solution?

Comment: @Mobin I see what you mean, this works well with a plane and Shrinkwrap set to `Nearest Surface Project` -> `Outside Surface`. I believe the circle doesn't work this way because it has no edges along the inside. Is there a way to add inside edges/faces to a circle?

Comment: you can add quick loops by selecting the face in edit mode and pressing i. although there are better methods this is the quickest one.

Comment: I really wouldn't mess with the topology, especially if your character is going to deform. I would use a UV-mapped texture to color the fur, as shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9025/35559), and in other answers. You can also use textures to control other aspects of the fur.. length, density, etc. If there's something you think you can't do this way, let us know.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank you for the suggestion, that sounds interesting. I think this might be a bit beyond the scope of my current skills.. I will definitely add UV wrapping and such to my list of things to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have arrived at a solution thanks to the comments by @Mobin.

Place circle mesh where you want it with `Snapping` -> `Face`

`Circle mesh` -> `Edit mode` -> `Select face` -> `I to inset` and create internal geometry. A few loop cuts to improve its ability to bend.

[image]

You need to get rid of the vertices in the middle, or the geometry does strange things when applying the shrinkwrap.

Then you give the circle a shrinkwrap modifier. `Modifiers` -> `Shrinkwrap`
Set the body as the target, change the offset to the smallest amount that doesn't clip through.

[image]