# Make hair particles different colors on the same mesh?

Tags: particles, color, hair

Hello all I am wondering if there is a way to have a my hair/fur show up as 2 different colors on the same mesh? Im not looking for anything fancy just a hard split in the colors.The only guides i can find are about root to tip gradients or natural coloration using the nodes.

[image]

Basically I just want the pink assigned faces to have pink hair while the green has green hair.
Thanks!

Comment: check out https://blog.michelanders.nl/2015/02/using-vertex-colors-to-color-hair-in_14.html

Answer (score 2):

Having more fun with Materials, here's the "Moonboots" technique that uses a single Particle System that relies on Texture Paint on the UV mapping of the object.

I create two material slots, one for the mesh surface faces (named "Yellow") and one for the Particle System (named "RBG Texture Paint").  I could have used the same "RBG Texture Paint" on both the mesh and hair, if I wanted the mesh surface and hair strand colors to align.

[image]

Here I choose the Hair PS material slot "RBG Texture Paint":

[image]

In the Texture Paint editor (left hand panel), I created an image (internal to the blend file) and painted areas using the UV Map (displayed) as a guide to the faces.  I had divided the cylinder edges in half; is why there are two "column" rows, and then the two circular areas for the end faces.

[image]

Then in the right hand panel, in the Material editor,  I referenced the "red grn blu" image from the Texture editor creation.

Here is my example: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to do it in another way than with 2 particle systems, that said you can do it in ***Cycles*** if your emitter has an ***Image Texture***:

Once you've created your emitter material with an *Image Texture*, give a material to your particle with this setup: Use the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate*, on the bottom of the *Texture Coordinate* select the emitter object as *Object* and enable *From Instancer* so that the particles inherit the emitter colors:

[image]

Comment: I used your Texture Paint technique and herein posted a "single PS" solution.  I call it the "Moonboots" technique

Answer (score 0):

There is some pertinent discussion [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190746/particle-color-from-emitters-shader-color-without-any-textures) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9018/two-different-materials-in-one-particles-system).

I would divide the Hair into two different Particle Systems that can each have their own Material assigned to the render:

[image]

The downside is that you aren't sharing all the parameters, and have to set up your hair Emission counts for each with some trial and error.

I cannot find any Shader input that can make use of a vertex group boolean into a color chooser, which is a sad deficiency IMHO.

[image]

and oh my the blender-exchange is actually working today.  here is my 3.0 example file [image]