# Setup a decal material in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I'm trying to setup a image decal in cycles, and I can't figure how to setup the nodes to work fine. Does anyone know the solution?

[blendFile](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31125)

[image: node setup]

Comment: For your case, just turn the mixing up to 1; How the f--- did you manage to get a viewer node into the material?!

Comment: ahh, node wrangler addon, by Bartek Skorupa, one of my favourite addons. You can do a lot of things, for example, mix nodes with ALT+rightclick drags.

Comment: the mix=1 doesn't use the second image alpha, so it turns black

Comment: oh, damn. I just figured out. Just have to plug the alpha value into the factor socket

Comment: well it seems related, but here the alpha is set in the mix color node, not in the mix shader. It won't hurt to have it around in the case someone has the same question in the future.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8706/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1258/599

Comment: @someonewithpc `@DavidGasku` Note that [node wrangler](https://github.com/gregzaal/node_wrangler/) is actually by Greg Zaal, but it was combined with [node efficiency tools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Nodes/Nodes_Efficiency_Tools) by Bartek Skorupa and then bundled with blender by default. It has lots of interesting features, but I mainly just use Ctrl+Shift+Click :)

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3 :) Node Wrangler is a joint effort between Bartek and I, and even gets some commits from other devs occasionally. That repo on github is no longer the one we use, since the add-on is in blender by default now - so everyone's already got it installed and just needs to enable it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just have to plug the alpha value of the decal into the factor socket of the mix node. Hope it is useful for someone in the future.

[image: solution]