# How to add Wear & Tear effect in a Texture

Tags: texturing

I just need help to make my scene look like the scene in DYING LIGHT Game at least similar. the wear-and-tear look is somewhat missing, I'm a beginner in blender so i really don't know how to achieve this look, not really sure if its texture painting etc.i circled it red.

- blood stains
- crack in the wall
- tear in the sofa
- bulb wires and ivy (kindly disregard this, i'll search for this in YouTube instead but if you know one kindly pass on the link)

Thank you so much

[image: Dying light]

Comment: see if [this answer helps](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15208/5113)

Comment: @Chebhou thank you so much, that solves the blood stains and the crack in wall.

how about the tear in the couch?

Comment: i think that needs some modelling , but you may get a better solution

Comment: Well you take a hammer, and you stand just so...

Comment: @Chebhou modeling? Ok. so texture and materials won't do the job?Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Once you've darkened the recessed and worn areas, you should be able to turn up the light intensity to achieve that sunlight bloom effect that we see in the top image.  For some tips on how to do this->see below.

Comment: You might also want to adjust the number of Global Illumination bounces to account for different times of the day.  Fewer bounces for late afternoon.  Maybe just one or two bounces should help get that appearance of a darker and more enclosed area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wear and tear detail on the surfaces of the models can be painted in using bump maps that are either imported or created using Blender's Texture Paint tools. Procedural textures also work well for this.

Start with a grayscale image(set to non-color) and connect this to Displacement socket of the Cycles Material output node.

[image]

The bump map node does not currently work for baking normal maps in Cycles.  Only use the displacement socket for now when baking.

[image]

Next, bake the texture so it can be used in the game engine this is supposed to be for(I'm making an assumption that this is what you are doing ;) Be sure to select the texture node that is being baked to so that the baker tool accesses the proper texture.  It should be active in the editor.

[image]

Now test the results by plugging the normal map into the shaders' normal socket.

[image]

---

You can bake normal maps using either Blender Render(Internal) or Cycles.  For many situations the results should be identical.

With Cycles, there is the additional option of using a custom defined cage when working with difficult geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Another common way to capture/add detail is to bake Ambient Occlusion(AO).

AO can be used to simulate the subtle indirect shadows that show up in recessed areas.

AO can also be used to as a mix factor for two different colors(or textures).

In the following example a photo of moss is being mixed with light gray using the baked Ambient Occlusion map.  The moss shows up where the AO map is darker.  A normal map is also being used here.

[image]

You can bake a simple AO map using Cycles with the following settings.

Basically it's just a Diffuse shader that has it's color set to pure white.  (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

The sky is a simple colored background that is also set to (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).

Direct lighting should be used.  Global illumination will fade the effect and one or two bounces can be used to soften the result if it's too dark in some areas.

It's baked using the Combined pass.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One of the three common ways that people add extra detail to a scene is to use a black and white image to mix between two shaders.

The following image shows a baked Ambient Occlusion image that is used to mix between a Glossy shader and a Diffuse shader.

There are several methods people use to generate these maps.

(i) Texture paint, change the color for edges and scratches and you can make these areas more Diffuse just as they would be for a real worn object.  A scratched surface tends to be less shiny.

(ii) Use Ambient Occulsion as shown in one of the other answers.  Recessed areas tend to accumulate gunk and goo and are more difficult to clean so we might expect these areas to be less shiny.

(iii) You can bake the results of the 'Vertex Paint Mode->Paint->Dirty Vertex Colors tool'
    (iiib)  Recently, a new attribute type has been added to Cycles nodes and is called the Node:Input->Geometry->Pointiness attribute.  It can be used for both baking and camera renders to accentuate the curvature of the model.

Sharp areas on the model will stand out from the flatter regions and this can be used as a blending factor.

The Vertex Dirty Vertex Colors tool can be used mostly the same way but the Pointiness attribute is more simple to use and is non-destructive to the model.

[image]

Comment: this is NOT for a game engine or for a game its just a fan art.im using cycles as my renderer...can i still use these methods you posted?

Comment: thank you so .this is very helpful.. im fairly new to blender so it will take me time to understand this concept =).

Comment: I did that all with Cycles.  If it's staying in Cycles you can avoid a lot of the texture baking.  I would still bake the Ambient Occlusion since Global Illumination fades AO if it's not baked.

Comment: If you bake normal maps, you can use lower poly counts.

Comment: I guess the basic concept would be as follows for mixing masks.  When the texture is black, it sets the mix ratio to 0.0.  When the texture is white, it sets the mix ratio to 1.0.  If the texture is grey, the value is somewhere between 0.0 and 1.0.    It works the same way as if you use the slider bar in the Color mix node for a single value except that when using a texture, the mixing takes place per-pixel instead of per-object.