# How can I add a texture to a specific face?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have a cylinder (imported from Creo, in .obj), to which I've added a material, steel and rendered it. It looks great.

I've now cut it in half, and want to see a different texture on the cut face, how do I do that in Cycles?

I tried diffent tutorials from that site but doesn't work with Cycles and imported .obj.

Here is an outside view:

[image: outside view]

Then, when cut, the blueish part should show the cutting tool path leaving marks in the metal.

[image: cutting tool path]

Marks or scratches could be like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=steel%20texture&biw=1236&bih=787&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiQ5u2M7YnMAhWFrB4KHc2lCE4Q_AUIBigB#imgrc=ghp2KGK6LIK7CM%3A).

Comment: Please include an image of your work to clarify your question.  Also include an image from the web of an example scratches that suit you.

Comment: possible duplicate of any of these: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32166/adding-surface-scratches or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21283/add-scratches-to-a-material-in-cycles or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32166/adding-surface-scratches/32206#32206

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/procedurally-generating-wear-on-an-object and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/how-to-add-wear-tear-effect-in-a-texture and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32494/how-to-make-dirty-looking-object/33054#33054

Comment: ok, I have no problem creating scratches all over, I just want marks on the cut face of the part.

Comment: Maybe bump and specular maps will do what you want to. Note that bump map imitates roughness while doesn't make changes to geometry. If you plan to look at cut parts from the side view when relief should reveal itself then consider **Displace** modifier.

Comment: thanks, I could try that, but my biggest problem is how to select the face I want to add this new texture to?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I think I found a way (since unwrapping doesn't seem to work for me).

1. Select the part, go to edit mode, do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and choose Face
2. Then select the face of the part I want to add texture to (there's a bunch of little triangles that need to be selected)
3. Next, assign a new material to that face, and deal with texture in Nodes.

Comment: Your question is about scratches, but this answer is just about assigning a different material about your mesh. I think either your original question needs to be edited to clarify what you're looking for or this answer expanded as 'deal with the texture in Nodes' does not explain how to create scratches.

Comment: Done, edited. I just wanted to know how to place a texture on a single face, it can be scratches, marks bumps or whatever.