# How to bake wireframe to texture? no i'm not referring to export uv

Tags: uv, texture-baking, wireframe

i'm modeling an hard surface with subdivision, bevels and so on.
I would like to bake the final wireframe to texture, with all the subsurf, bevels, bools etc.
Is it possible?

Comment: Just in case you need a wireframe not baked but rendered  ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVzWaf8ZK04

Comment: This seams to be what you are looking for https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51802

Comment: Ah, am I right - you want texture with wireframe that includes subsurface and bevel topology generated by modifiers without apply? Can you give us some reference image? Because like with subsurface the result would be a big mess ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want but you could duplicate your object, apply all the modifiers to the copy, in *Edit* mode/*Face Select* mode, select all and inset individual faces (double <kbd>i</kbd>), give a color to the selection, invert selection and give another color to the wireframe, then bake the result?

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but this is a destructive method, i would like to keep my modifiers in order to easily modify the mesh if needed

Comment: what do you mean by "destructive method"? Yes you need to apply the modifiers but you can keep the original with its modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

[Wireframe node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/wireframe.html) should be possible to bake as any other material ... it just goes to triangulated. Probably because all meshes are triangulated for rendering?

[image]

Comment: mmh sound interesting, i'll give it a try!