# How to add wires to my character?

Tags: modeling, texturing, edit-mode

I want to make my model looking like it is made of wires (the entire model).

How can I do this? I can just make the model texture look like wires or actual tubes? The wires I'm thinking of are similar to fnaf sister location tubing, its the best way I can describe it.

[image]

looks something like this his head

[image]

like sister location wires

Comment: Wireframe Modifier?

Comment: @JustImpact Can you describe it a bit more? Are there holes in the model? The suggested Wireframe Modifier makes the edges of the mesh solid and the faces of the mesh become holes.
Or is the wire more a pattern? There are offsets on your picture and it looks solid.
Maybe this helps? [Bake wireframe to texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/201809/107598)

Comment: @Blunder thank you for the feedback and thank you for your assit to help, however my design doesnt look good with this method. i remember trying this many months ago. thanks for the help anyway,  if you want to know what i meant as wires this link will show you a picture of a rire that looks similar to what i need https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffnaf-sister-location.fandom.com%2Fwiki%2FYenndo&psig=AOvVaw22lP1ImLeud3vOYlsuM77i&ust=1606472436319000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLCdw6z-n-0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to make your mesh made of wire is using wire modifier.  If you want to fill the holes between wires your can check replace original. Like this effect:
[image]
Again if you want to make the wire look more like organic,  you can add a bunch of subsurface modifier. Like this :
[image]
Other than that,  if you want to see some interesting effect,  you can use tissue addon. Thankfully it comes with blender,  you just have to enable it.  And the effect should look like this:[image]
Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sculpting them on, I have used sculpting for a while and have found that if you want high levels of detail, this is the thing to do it.

However due to this it could be difficult finding textures to what you image shows so you might need to look into that.

Comment: hi, does anyone know where that one answer was one this because it had a humanoid guy made of wires using nodes but i cant find it, it was on here somewhere its an actual question answer your self answer so if anyone can find it i will be most greatful