# I have textures of wood but how to make a wet wood out of that?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]I have a complete wood textures including col,nor,dis,gloss,refle etc..
Can anyone say how to make a wet wood out of that?

Comment: Please add also your material setup, this is important if you want to have more reflections on this wet map.

Comment: related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39866/adding-imprints-on-objects/41704#41704https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39866/adding-imprints-on-objects/41704#41704

Comment: Either procedurally darken the texture with some color mixing effect, or find another darker wood texture and mix it with the previous using some sort of mask.