# How to put an Image Texture over a material in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor

I've scored the internet looking for a solution but I have yet to find one that works with my current set up. I have a face drawn over my uv map and I want to apply it to my object.

Everything but the eyes are transparent.

I want to be able to add this to my object which already has a material without the material altering the image texture or the image texture being applied and the material being covered.

Here is my node setup:
[image: nodes]

I'm just not sure where to put the Image Texture Node. ANy thoughts?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: See also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/setup-a-decal-material-in-cycles

Answer (score 3):

So I appreciate the related links. I was able to tinker around with my setup and get the image texture to appear over my material below.

I needed to:

1. Add another Mix Shader Node
2. Plug the result of the material shader to its shader slot
3. Then I added a text coordinate connected the UV slot to an Image Texture
4. Opened my Uvimage in the image text. node
5. Added a Diffuse BSDF and connected Image Text to that
6. Then connected Diffuse BSDF to the new Mix shader
7. Then connected the alpha slot of the Image Text to Fac slot on the new Mix Shader (to take into account the png image's transparent background)

[image: node setup]