# surface image detail

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image

I want to add surface details on top of a surface material with transparency maintained.
For example if i have a bowl with a blue Lacquered surface I might want to add a band of detail that still shows the blue surface in the transparent parts. The detail might be a flower or something like that. I can select a band of faces and assign a new material to that band but i cant find a way to cleanly map a series of small images (1 image tiled around) around the band and cant see the surface underneath.
Hope that makes sense
[image: Texture Map and nodes]

Comment: To make this question answerable: add an example ikage of your trxture, object and desired result (stock). Also.include the renderer Tag (internal or cycles).

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/setup-a-decal-material-in-cycles