# Putting image on model in cycles

Tags: modeling, image

I wanted to put an image from a company onto my 3D model. How would I do this with blender cycles? I have the image file and I want to put it on the torso of my character (which is about 4 faces put together) I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup a decal material in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/setup-a-decal-material-in-cycles) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Answer (score -2):

Add a new material and go to compositing then add image texture into the diffuse bsdf

Comment: You are confusing composting and material nodes. Both are accessed on the **node editor** window, but are used for different processes. It is not the same.