# How to have 2 Mats w/alpha each and a base Mat on the same object?

Tags: materials

I need to have the Base.Color material on all the cube faces. With the setup I have I cannot. I have to choose between the materials with Alpha, or the Base.Color material.
I did try adding a 2nd UV map but apparently only one can be renderable at the time.
Thanks in advance guys.

[image]

Comment: Have you assigned two different materials to two different faces? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: As the screenshot shows: 3 materials have been assigned to one cube (Choc.Donut, Blue.Donut, and Base.Color). The tricky part in my case is that I need 2 materials on the same set of polygons: the base material, and a texture with alpha on top of it.

Comment: So if your intention is to create decals, there are other posts on the matter: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/setup-a-decal-material-in-cycles

Comment: Excellent! Yes, that's just what I needed! Thanks a bunch Denis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use decals to place textures over the main texture. See other answers: [Setup a decal material in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/setup-a-decal-material-in-cycles)