# Transparent Texture doesnt come up correctly in texture shading. A glitch?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, image, transparency

I have 2 questions:

1. I am using a texture with a transparent alpha channel. It renders alright, but it displays in the *3D Viewport's* texture shading mode all wrong, as you can see below. Is this a glitch or did I do something wrong?

[image: This is how it looks now.]

[image: This is how it renders.]

2. Is there any way I can make the grey area outside the texture a different shader? Everytime I put a UVmap there, thinking nothing would appear on the model, the texture still appears! Is it obligatory to fit everything in that little square?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: As for "..make the grey area outside the texture image empty of texture" I think you mean to avoid tiling image texture which uses UV coordinates; for answer see  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/cycles-option-to-turn-off-texture-tiling. Texture shading mode can be inaccurate with textures with alpha channel, it's better to check it once rendered. Please ask one question per post, thanks.

Comment: Starting your question with, "I have two questions" is a bad idea. If you have two questions, ask two separate questions.